# Pass parameter to SQLPLUS package function from Windows batch

Tags: function, batch-file, parameters, package, sqlplus

there,

I need to pass a Date parameter in a Windows batch to a sqlplus package function. tried to search the web and this site, only find something that pass parameter directly to a script such as a select statement, not fit for my case:

1. Get DB system date from sql package function in the batch and return the date as a parameter;
2. Pass the returned date to next sql package function to create a table with dummy data;
3. use the same date parameter to generate data for final output.

## This is the batch file "AML_Gen_Data.bat"

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set FICAPRD_LOGIN=/@CRH1_FICAPRD
set FICAPRD_HOME=D:\TMP\AML
set FICAPRD_BIN=%FICAPRD_HOME%\bin
set FICAPRD_PATH_TEMPLATE=%FICAPRD_HOME%\template
set FICAPRD_PATH_SQL=%FICAPRD_HOME%\sql
set FICAPRD_PATH_LOG=%FICAPRD_HOME%\log
set FICAPRD_PATH_DAT=%FICAPRD_HOME%\data

call :PROCRESS

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (

GOTO SUCCESS

) ELSE (

GOTO ERROR
)

:SUCCESS 
ECHO CONTROL-M FLAG : SUCCESS
GOTO END

:ERROR
ECHO CONTROL-M FLAG : FAILED
GOTO END

:END

GOTO :eof

:PROCRESS
ECHO ================START======================
ECHO Started %DATE% %TIME%

REM DB system date does not equal to calendar date
REM The returned date is to determine data generation date
<Generation_date> = <SQL package function to get DB system date>

REM create table and fill in with test data
ECHO Creating table T_FICA_SAS_CDD_EVENT... %DATE% %TIME%
sqlplus -S %FICAPRD_LOGIN%  @%FICAPRD_PATH_SQL%\execute_f_fica_sas_cdd_event2.sql <Generation_date>

REM Data massage to get useful data and put the data into a table called SAS_Output
REM Still need to use the date parameter
ECHO Generating data from T_FICA_SAS_CDD_EVENT... %DATE% %TIME%
sqlplus -S %FICAPRD_LOGIN%  @%FICAPRD_PATH_SQL%\gen_sas_cdd_event.sql <Generation_date>

REM Print the data from SAS_Output to CSV file
ECHO Opening sas_cdd_event.csv... %DATE% %TIME%
sqlplus -S %FICAPRD_LOGIN%  @%FICAPRD_PATH_SQL%\get_sas_output.sql %FICAPRD_PATH_DAT%\AML_EVENT_%date:~6,4%%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%.csv
ECHO Execute_f_fica_sas_cdd_event Ended %DATE% %TIME%

ECHO ================END====================== %DATE% %TIME%
EXIT /B
```

=====================================================================

This is the file "execute_f_fica_sas_cdd_event.sql".
Originally it was hardcoded with a date and I needed to change the date
every time to generate data, but now want to eliminate this step by getting the
DB system date in the batch and pass to package function automatically.

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

declare
   v_result     varchar2(1);
--   v_report_date varchar(8) := '20201130';
   v_report_date varchar(8);
   
begin
   v_result  := FICAPRD.PKG_FICA_SAS.f_fica_sas_cdd_event (v_report_date);
end;
/
exit
```

=====================================================================

This is the file "gen_sas_cdd_event.sql"

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON


declare
   v_result     varchar2(1);
--   v_report_date varchar(8) := '20201130';
   v_report_date varchar(8);
   
begin
   v_result  := FICAPRD.PKG_FICA_SAS.f_fica_sas_cdd_gen_event (v_report_date);
end;
/
exit
```

=====================================================================

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help in my case.

Comment: Could you give us your sqlplus client version ? From Oracle 12c, the DATE data type is supported for sqlplus bind variables defined with the `VARIABLE` command.

Comment: This is my sqlplus version:   SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the date as a sqlplus parameter string and then cast it to a date and use it in your PLSQL block as a bind. **Take care that you need to adapt the format *MM/DD/YYYY* or *MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS* (US locales here) in the sql `EXEC :MY_DATE` to your current locales**. To avoid that, check the second part with a better way to handle that.

### In AML_Gen_Data.bat

```
...
sqlplus -S %FICAPRD_LOGIN%  @%FICAPRD_PATH_SQL%\execute_f_fica_sas_cdd_event2.sql "%DATE%"
# Note than you can passe the full date with "%DATE% %TIME%"
...
sqlplus -S %FICAPRD_LOGIN%  @%FICAPRD_PATH_SQL%\gen_sas_cdd_event.sql "%DATE%"
# Note than you can passe the full date with "%DATE% %TIME%"
```

### In execute_f_fica_sas_cdd_event.sql

```sql
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
-- For Oracle 12c and +. You need to adapt MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS to your current locales
VAR MY_DATE DATE
EXEC :MY_DATE := TO_DATE('&1', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
-- In case you need the full date
-- EXEC :MY_DATE := TO_DATE(SUBSTR('&1',1,INSTR('&1','.')-1), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

declare
   v_result     varchar2(1);
   -- v_report_date varchar(8) := '20201130';
   v_report_date varchar(8) := TO_CHAR(:MY_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
   
begin
   v_result  := FICAPRD.PKG_FICA_SAS.f_fica_sas_cdd_event (v_report_date);
end;
/
exit
```

### In gen_sas_cdd_event.sql

```sql
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
-- For Oracle 12c and +. You need to adapt MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS to your current locales
VAR MY_DATE DATE
EXEC :MY_DATE := TO_DATE('&1', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
-- In case you need the full date
-- EXEC :MY_DATE := TO_DATE(SUBSTR('&1',1,INSTR('&1','.')-1), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');


declare
   v_result     varchar2(1);
--   v_report_date varchar(8) := '20201130';
   v_report_date varchar(8) := TO_CHAR(:MY_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
   
begin
   v_result  := FICAPRD.PKG_FICA_SAS.f_fica_sas_cdd_gen_event (v_report_date);
end;
/
exit
```

## A better way :

In your case, i suggest you to parse the date in your batch file in the form YYYYMMDD with powershell or the like as way to not depend of the current locales :

### In AML_Gen_Data.bat

```
...
FOR /F %%D IN ('powershell /C "Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd""') DO SET MY_DATE=%%D
sqlplus -S %FICAPRD_LOGIN%  @%FICAPRD_PATH_SQL%\execute_f_fica_sas_cdd_event2.sql "%MY_DATE%"
...
sqlplus -S %FICAPRD_LOGIN%  @%FICAPRD_PATH_SQL%\gen_sas_cdd_event.sql "%MY_DATE%"
```

### In execute_f_fica_sas_cdd_event.sql

```sql
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

declare
   v_result     varchar2(1);
   -- v_report_date varchar(8) := '20201130';
   v_report_date varchar(8) := '&1';
   
begin
   v_result  := FICAPRD.PKG_FICA_SAS.f_fica_sas_cdd_event (v_report_date);
end;
/
exit
```

### In gen_sas_cdd_event.sql

```sql
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERM OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

declare
   v_result     varchar2(1);
--   v_report_date varchar(8) := '20201130';
   v_report_date varchar(8) := '&1';
   
begin
   v_result  := FICAPRD.PKG_FICA_SAS.f_fica_sas_cdd_gen_event (v_report_date);
end;
/
exit
```